# Como manter o usuario autenticado?

Tags: swift, xcode

Estou utilizando [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) para enviar a requisição de autenticação assim:

```
let user = "user"
let password = "password"

Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/\(user)/\(password)")
         .authenticate(user: user, password: password)
         .responseJSON { response in
             debugPrint(response)
       // Aqui verifico se foi autenticado e redireciono para a view principal.

}
```

Minha dúvida é, como  posso salvar a autenticação para que o usuário não precise logar novamente quando entrar no aplicativo, no PHP eu usaria `$_SESSION`   mas no `swift` eu não sei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Swift você pode usar o [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/) para persistir estes dados.

Para salvar o usuário e senha use:

**SWIFT 2**

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userDefaults.setObject("joaosilva", forKey: "username")
userDefaults.setObject("senha1234", forKey: "password")
```

**SWIFT 3**

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("joaosilva", forKey: "username")
UserDefaults.standard.set("senha1234", forKey: "password")
```

Para recuperar os dados use:

**SWIFT 2**

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let username = userDefaults.stringForKey("username")
let password = userDefaults.stringForKey("password")
```

**SWIFT 3**

```
let username = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "username")
let password = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "password")
```